# C Pointer notation

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel

I'm trying to do a deep dive into the linux source code and I'm seeing the following pattern of embedding a struct *list_head* to form a doubly linked list, this is on **skbuff.h**

```
struct sk_buff {
    union {
        struct {
            /* These two members must be first to match sk_buff_head. */
            struct sk_buff      *next;
            struct sk_buff      *prev;
        };
    
        ...
        struct list_head    list; <- list_head as above mentioned
    };

    ...
}
```

So, basically, whenever you want access some member of the list you need some pointer to *list_head*, move it however you want and when you are in the position you need use this convenient macro defined on **include/linux/container_of.h** to get an outer reference (a reference to sk_buff->*<some member>* for example)

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({                      \
    void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);                               \
    static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) ||   \
                  __same_type(*(ptr), void),                    \
                  "pointer type mismatch in container_of()");   \
    ((type *)(__mptr - offsetof(type, member))); })
```

But I'm having trouble at understanding what **container_of** macro do, especially what **((type *)0)->member)** means (I never saw that kind of pointer to 0) and why **((type *)(__mptr - offsetof(type, member))** works (I believe my concern here is how to use it in the context of mantaining the linked list and not just accesing a member of a given struct).

Could someone please help explaining the above two points about **container_of** macro ?, I'm not a noob on C but I never saw those patterns before and I was unable to get some interesting results on Google.

Really thanks, cheers.

Comment: I think the idea is that you have a pointer to a member of a structure, and from that pointer you want to obtain the address of the structure itself.  For example, if you have `struct foo {int a; int b;}` and you have a pointer to the `b` field of an instance of that structure, you can use the macro to obtain the address of the structure itself.

Comment: `((type *)0)->member)`: `(type *)` is a cast to pointer to type.  0 is an object that allows that cast.  Now that you have pointer to the type, it tries to access the struct pointer's `member`.  It's part of a static_assert that can checks if it's possible and otherwise generates an error message.